# Command or keystroke to redraw an X Window app screen?

Tags: gui, x-windows

I'm using an X Window application running on a remote RHEL9 host, and there is an apparent [bug](https://github.com/XQuartz/XQuartz/issues/323) in my X client display software that causes graphical garbage to accumulate in the app window.

I'm hopeful that a bugfix is coming.  In the meantime, I'm just trying to get my daily work done.

One way to mitigate the effects of the bug might be to just redraw the application window from scratch every few minutes, in hopes that this would clear away the garbage.

Is there a command or keystroke that tells X to redraw the window?  Something like <kbd>Ctrl-L</kbd> for curses apps?

Comment: Does minimizing and restoring the window cause its refresh?